# how to order firebase firestore data by the field's value i.e. "reason" field name and its values may be "spam", "nudity" etc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

[image: here is the firestore documen]

I want to sort the data by the "reason" field's values like "spam" , "nudity" and other reasons. could you please help me with that.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to confirm if you wanna just sort the data in asc or desc order, or do you wanna like group into categories?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?

Comment: the following answer worked for me. Actually I knew that thing, but my mind was stuck. and the answer worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For version 8**

```
yourdatabaseRef.where("reason", "==", "fieldNameProvided")
```

if you then want to order it just add

```
orderBy("parameter", "desc");
```

**For Version 9**

```
import { query, where, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q = query(yourdatabaseRef, where("reason", "==", "fieldNameProvided"));
```

if you then want to order it, make a little change:

```
const q = query(yourdatabaseRef, where("reason", "==", "fieldNameProvided"), ("parameter", "desc"));
```

I hope this helps

Comment: yeah you are right, actually the orderBy also filters the data, my mind was stuck there, thank you for your effort.

Comment: This only fetches data matching single value not all values in reason field.